# Check if exactly one variable is not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a trigger in my sql-server 2008 database I need to check if exactly one variable is not null. This code does what I need, but can it be done in fewer lines and more readable?

```
DECLARE @string varchar
DECLARE @float float
DECLARE @bit bit
DECLARE @int int

Set @string=NULL  -- Exactly one of these variables needs to be set
Set @float=NULL   --
Set @bit=NULL     -- 
Set @int=NULL     --

IF(   (@string is not null AND COALESCE(@float, @bit, @int) IS NULL)
    OR (@float is not null AND COALESCE(@string, @bit, @int) IS NULL)
    OR (@bit is not null AND COALESCE(@string, @float, @int) IS NULL)
    OR (@int is not null AND COALESCE(@string, @float, @bit) IS NULL)
)
print ' ok'
ELSE 
print ' not ok'
```

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this - just want to check that you're aware that a trigger fires for all rows updated by the statement. So if you've got something like `select @string = string, @float = float ... from inserted`, your trigger is already broken when it comes to multirow inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: Also, if this is to ensure that integrity of the underlying table, (and this is the only check required), it would be better to put whatever predicate you end up with in a CHECK constraint, rather than a trigger.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about multiple rows. Got to look into that.

The reason I need a trigger is that I got to check the constraint against another table, which determines the field that is allowed to be set. 

Maybe I'll put the "only one" condition into a CHECK constraint and check against the table in the trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) =1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
FROM 
(VALUES (CAST(@string AS SQL_VARIANT)),(@float),(@bit),(@int)) T (c)
```

Comment: I like the brevity of this one.
Here's an extra challenge: Can this be modified so it can go into a CHECK constraint?

Comment: I'll mark this as answer to the question. Although Damiens answer solves my problem, I believe this is the shortest answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not necessarily sure it's any more readable (although I guess if you abstracted it to a function it might be) but

```
if((case when @string is null then 0 else 1 end + 
    case when @float  is null then 0 else 1 end +
    case when @bit    is null then 0 else 1 end + 
    case when @int    is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1) 
  ....
```

is a little more flexible?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I was being clever, but this will only work if none of the 4 varibles can have the exact same value, so it's not useful in many cases.  I'll post it anyway:

```
IF(   
(COALESCE(@string,@float, @bit, @int) IS NULL)     
OR (COALESCE(@string, @float, @bit, @int) != COALESCE(@int, @bit, @float, @string))
) 
print 'not ok' 
ELSE  print 'ok'
```

COALESCE evals from left to right until it hits a NOT NULL value, so if you invert the order you'll get a different result if you have more than one var. set (unless the varibles can have the same value at the same time)

Comment: This query will also run into trouble if the string value can't be converted into a number.

Comment: Upvoting because this *can* be useful, and was the first thing I thought of when approaching a similar problem for myself, but it has the stated problem; if the values of at least two variables are equal it can give a false negative.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know the type of setup you're creating. In those circumstances, I usually define me data structures as:

```
CREATE TABLE DataItems (
    DataItemID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Name varchar(10) not null,
    TypeRequired varchar(6) not null,
    constraint PK_DataItems PRIMARY KEY (DataItemID),
    constraint CK_TypeRequired CHECK (TypeRequired in ('STRING','FLOAT','BIT','INT'),
    constraint UQ_DataItems_TypeCheck UNIQUE (DataItemID,TypeRequired)
)
```

note that I've made `DataItemID,TypeRequired` a superkey, so I can reference it in a foreign key constraint.

Now, in the table that's collecting the data:

```
CREATE TABLE Answers (
    AnswerID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    /* Other columns to FK to e.g. Client, Users, Session, whatever */
    DataItemID int not null,
    Type varchar(6) not null,
    StringValue varchar(max) null,
    FloatValue float null,
    BitValue bit null,
    IntValue int null,
    constraint PK_Answers PRIMARY KEY (AnswerID),
    constraint FK_Answers_DataItems FOREIGN KEY (DataItemID) references DataItems (DataItemID),
    constraint FK_Answers_DataItems_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY (DataItemID,Type) references DataItems (DataItemID,TypeRequired),
    constraint CK_Answers_TypeCheck CHECK (
        (FloatValue is null or TypeRequired = 'FLOAT') and
        (StringValue is null or TypeRequired = 'STRING') and
        (BitValue is null or TypeRequired = 'BIT') and
        (IntValue is null or TypeRequired = 'INT')),
    constraint CK_Answers_NotNUll CHECK (
        FloatValue is not null or StringValue is not null or BitValue is not null or IntValue is not null)
)
```

The second foreign key constraint ensures the type column matches the defined type for the data item, and the pair of check constraints ensure that exactly one column (and the right column) is not null.

If you need to hide the Type column from the users, then I'd suggest renaming the above table (e.g. `_Answers`) creating a view with an insert trigger:

```
CREATE VIEW Answers
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
     SELECT
         AnswerID,
         DataItemID,
         StringValue,
         FloatValue,
         BitValue,
         IntValue
     FROM
         dbo._Answers

CREATE TRIGGER T_Answers_I
ON Answers
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
     INSERT INTO _Answers (DataItemID,Type,StringValue,FloatValue,BitValue,IntValue)
     SELECT i.DataItemID,di.Type,i.StringValue,i.FloatValue,i.BitValue,i.IntValue
     FROM inserted i inner join DataItems di on i.DataItemID = di.DataItemID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a solution to my problem, although it's not the answer to the question. ;-)

Only thing I find a little bit unsightly about this is saving the type column twice and having the strings of the allowed types at two locations in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution but it isn't any fewer lines.  It uses the bitwise XOR operator.  I'm not sure if I like it or not - but it does mean that each variable only gets checked once rather than on each line so potentially it satisfies your readability requirement:

```
DECLARE @string varchar
DECLARE @float float
DECLARE @bit bit
DECLARE @int int

SET @string=NULL  -- Exactly one of these variables needs to be set
SET @float=NULL  --
SET @bit=NULL    -- 
SET @int=NULL     --


if  ((case when @string is null then 1 else 0 end) 
        ^ (case when @float is null then 1 else 0 end)
        ^ (case when @bit is null then 1 else 0 end)
        ^ (case when @int is null then 1 else 0 end)) = 1
print 'ok'
else
print 'not ok'
```

Comments? Criticisms?  Also not sure how efficient the `CASE` statements are.

Answer (score 1):

Can't we check by this:

```
IF ISNULL(@string, '') <> ''
    OR ISNULL(@float, 0) <> 0
    OR @bit IS NOT NULL
    OR ISNULL(@int, 0) <> 0
   PRINT 'There is atleast one value'
ELSE
   PRINT 'ALL ARE NULL'
```